# How to get matrix of checkboxes in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

[image]I need to display the checkboxes in tabular form as in attached image.

[image]

I have two tables in database with 3 and 6 records respectively. How to show them as in the above image i.e. in rows and columns in ASP.NET and c#?

[image]

Comment: I think you better to use Store Procedure to join the tables together first and then use GridView to show the query .

Comment: Please add more info ,so we can help you . like adding the tables and the relation between them .

Comment: I have not started working on the above cuz i dnt have any idea how to start it.I need to show checkboxes in tabular format so as per the tables data so that user can select the checkboxes and send the values in the DB.

Comment: Not able to think how to go about it

Comment: did you create the  project ?

Comment: add a new table having `View_ID` and `Privilage_ID` in it . .. then create a Store Procedure

Comment: I have join the tables select v.View_ID,v.View_Name,p.Privilege_ID,p.Privilege_Name from tblViews as v right outer join tblPrivileges p on v.View_ID = p.Privilege_ID. and got output as in image. How to use it to achieve tabular matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could go around solving this...

If you simply wish to display these six values and not do anything else, it might simply be easiest to create an `<asp:Table>` tag in your .aspx file and then add the content to it dynamically when loading the page.

If you have trouble with this just say so.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well to see how to do this from code behind.

---

edit:

If you wish to add the code retrieved from the database to the table you can use the following code (I am not sitting in front of a compiler so might contain errors):

```
foreach(String name in Privilige_NameList){
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tcTitle = new TableCell();
    tc1.Value = name;
    tr.Add(tc1);
    foreach(String checkboxTitle in view_nameList){
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Text = checkBoxTitle;
        tc.Add(cb);
        tr.Add(tc);
    }            
}
```

Comment: What is it you are having trouble with? Do you need assistance in the database retrieval or is it the setup of the table?

Comment: troubling setting up the table?

Comment: Added the code to add the rows and cells to the table from codebehind.

Comment: !!!I am able to produce the desired output of matrix checkboxes from the database. Now I want to send the values of the selected checkboxes to the other DB tables. Kindly suggest?